# Divide Rectangle with slanted divider with different views on each side?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to split a rectangle into two sides with a slanted divider with background web images like this:

[image]

I tried using a triangle but having trouble dividing it in the correct direction and angle. Below is my working code I'm trying:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("VS")
                    .bold()
                    .padding(4)
                    .background(.thinMaterial.opacity(0.8))
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100)
            .padding()
            .background(
                AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/id/1037/1600/400"), transaction: Transaction(animation: .easeInOut)) { phase in
                    switch phase {
                    case .empty:
                        ProgressView()
                    case let .success(image):
                        image
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .transition(.opacity)
                    default:
                        Color.red
                            .transition(.opacity)
                    }
                }
                .overlay(
                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/id/1041/1600/400"), transaction: Transaction(animation: .easeInOut)) { phase in
                        switch phase {
                        case .empty:
                            ProgressView()
                        case let .success(image):
                            image
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                .transition(.opacity)
                        default:
                            Color.blue
                                .transition(.opacity)
                        }
                    }
                    .clipShape(Triangle())
                )
            )
            .cornerRadius(4)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct Triangle: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        return path
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

How can I accomplish the "back-slash" divider like in my first screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to adjust the points in your `Triangle` to fit the shape that you desire. If you look at each point you currently have, you'll see that it matches the shape that it draws.

By adjusting a couple of the points, you can get the desired result:

```
struct Triangle: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.33, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX * 0.66, y: rect.maxY))
        return path
    }
}
```

[image]